# Compound shard key with _id field

Tags: mongodb, sharding, mongodb-3.2

I have documents like:

```json
{_id: "someid1", "bar": "somevaluebar1"}
{_id: "someid2", "foo": "somevaluefoo2", "bar": "somevaluebar2"}
{_id: "someid3", "foo": "somevaluefoo3", "zoo": "somevaluezoo3"}
{_id: "someid4", "zoo": "somevaluezoo4"}
```

If we query documents by "foo" the most and "bar" the second, does it make sense to create a compound shard key like `{ "foo" : 1, "bar" : 1, "_id" : 1 }` because "foo" and "bar" might be missing too?

When I tried to run this command

```js
sh.shardCollection("<your-db>", {{ "foo" : 1, "bar" : 1, "_id" : 1 }:"hashed"})
```

it gave me a syntax error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to rethink your shard key approach.

As at MongoDB 3.2:

- All fields in a [compound shard key](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/choose-a-shard-key/) must be present in all documents and will be immutable (i.e. the shard key for an existing document cannot be changed).
- A [hashed shard key](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-hashed/) is based on a single field, and does not support range queries.

It generally makes sense to have a shard key that supports your common queries so they can be [targeted at a subset of shards](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/sharded-cluster-query-router/#broadcast-operations-and-targeted-operations) with relevant data, but this doesn't appear to be possible in your case as both `foo` and `bar` are optional fields.

If your `_id` field provides good cardinality (i.e. large number of values) but is monotonically increasing (eg. default ObjectIDs) you could consider a hashed shard index on the `_id` field for good write distribution. The hashed index wouldn't support your common read queries (unless by specific `_id` values) so you would need a secondary index for your queries on `foo` and `bar` (i.e. {`foo:1, bar:1`}). The recommended secondary index(es) and order will depend on your common queries and sort order.

For further background information I suggest reviewing:

- [Considerations for Selecting Shard Keys](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/choose-a-shard-key/)
- [Use Indexes to Sort Query Results](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/sort-results-with-indexes/)
- [Optimizing MongoDB Compound Indexes](https://emptysqua.re/blog/optimizing-mongodb-compound-indexes/)